# Algorithm to calculate Risk Rewards ratio in trading?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, algorithm

Currently, I am developing a trading calculator where I need to calculate the ratio between Risk and Rewards (Risk:Rewards). But I am getting the ratio value in decimal **(0.21)** as I am directly dividing the Ratio value between Risk and Rewards (`this.ratio = this.risk / this.rewards;`)

*For Ex:* **Quantity** = 900, **Entry** = 1300, **Stoploss** = 1237 and **Target** = 1600

```
 this.risk = (Entry__c - Stoploss__c) * Quantity__c;
 this.rewards = (Target__c - Entry__c) * Quantity__c;
 this.ratio = this.risk / this.rewards;
```

But I want my ratio should display/convert to **(1:4.76)** or round off to **(1:5)**

[This online Risk Reward calculator is showing both the value](https://www.getknowtrading.com/risk-reward-ratio-calculator/)

[image: Screenshot from the online calculator]

[I have tried implementing this formula which is mentioned in this link but the results are going in an infinite loop because of the larger value](https://www.codespeedy.com/get-the-ratio-of-two-numbers-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you linked is quite overcomplicated. You certainly don't need a loop.

I think you simply want something like:

```
const ratio = "1:" + Math.round(this.rewards / this.risk);
```

Comment: Thank you! this works like a charm